# Create Excel from HTML using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using HTML code in a variable and I do not know how can I pass to generate Excel using PHPExcel.

I am able to generate Excel with load HTML file but if I want use HTML in a variable then I am confused. Please give me an idea on how to implement this.

My sample code is below.

```
<?php
       require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
       require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
       $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
       header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="name_of_file.xls"');
       header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
       $html ='<table><tr><td><font color="blue">Hello</font></td><td><font style="color: blue;">Rest</font></td></tr><tr><td><font style="color: green;">Next</font></td><td><font style="color: Yellow;">Back</font></td></tr></table>';
       $wizard = new PHPExcel_Helper_HTML;
       $richText = $wizard->buildTextRun($html);
       $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);                               
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $richText);   
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Sheet 1');  
       $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
       $objWriter->save('php://output', 'w'); 
        ?>
```

When I am using it in variable then its showing all in column vise but I want that all should come new row vise.

Comment: In HTML have `<form>` and submit that form. Then in PHP all HTML variables will be in `$_POST` superglobal

Comment: Thanx for your reply @Justinas. But I have to need to create multi-tabs in a single Excel file and all tabs have different HTML. HTML will fillup with dynamic values. So I want to use all html in different variables, where I will fill dynamic values. Is it possible using variables?

Comment: Thanx for improve this post @Dave